# Uniqueness and limit of a solution of an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, stability-in-odes

Consider the integral equation

$$y\left(x\right) = A + \int_{0}^{x}y^{2/3}\left(s\right) ds$$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}$.
What does this limit of general solution when A goes to 0 imply ? Which is 
\begin{align*}
        \frac{dy}{dx} &= y^{2/3}\left(x\right) \\
        \frac{dy}{y^{2/3}} &= dx \\
        \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{y^{2/3}} &= \int_{0}^{x} dx \\
        3y^{1/3}|_{0}^{x} &= x \\
        \left(y\left(x\right)\right)^{1/3} - \left(y\left(0\right)\right)^{1/3} &= \frac{x}{3} \\
        \left(y\left(x\right)\right)^{1/3} &= A^{1/3} + \frac{x}{3} \\
        \phi\left(x,A\right) = y\left(x\right) &= \left(A^{1/3} + \frac{x}{3}\right)^{3}
    \end{align*}
For what value(s) of $A$ can you be sure that the solution is unique ? What is the range of $\phi\left(x,A\right)$ for such value of $A$? Why ?